# Why i dont have marker in Google map API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am a beginner to  HTML and JavaScript  . I read a text file which contains longitude and Latitude. 
I read that text file and store it in 3 arrays. One contains longitude, One latitude and one contains ID.
Text file is like this: (you can store it for debugging purpose with my code below)

```
ID  LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
0   77.139305   28.795975
2   77.308929   28.486877
4   73.820680   18.464110
6   75.588783   26.599820
12  77.193575   28.559693
```

I read it and stored the column 1 , 2 and in col1, col2, col3 respectively.

Now the problem is the code below show me the marker on map only when I put the long lat manually but when I use the my column arrays it don't show me any marker whereas it shows map.

What i have in mind is to run this for loop in my code and it should render all the marker in the given map.(Yes it's true that i have stored all the Long and Lat and Id i can see on debugging).

My code is :

```
                for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++)
                {
                    col1[j] = array[i];
                    col2[j] = array[i + 1];
                    col3[j] = array[i + 2];
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);
                    var mapOptions =
                        {
                            zoom: 4,
                            center: myLatlng
                        }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Hello World!'
                    });
                    j++;
                };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating markers from external xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081324/creating-markers-from-external-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with your code...

- The map is declared inside the loop
- Your split does not work correctly
- The increments on your arrays to not step enough `i`
- The Latitude and Longitude's were backwards in the marker definition

I have made the following edits and have a fiddle for you to look at so you can merge the code... http://jsfiddle.net/b4fz30vc/

```
function initialize() {
    var data =
        "ID  LONGITUDE   LATITUDE\r\n" +
        "0   77.139305   28.795975\r\n" +
        "2   77.308929   28.486877\r\n" +
        "4   73.820680   18.464110\r\n" +
        "6   75.588783   26.599820\r\n" +
        "12  77.193575   28.559693\r\n";

    var s2 = data.replace(/^.*$/, "").replace(/\r\n/g, " ");
    var array = s2.split(/[ ]+/g);
    var col1 = [];
    var col2 = [];
    var col3 = [];
    var j = 0;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(73, 23)
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        col1[j] = array[i];
        col2[j] = array[i++];
        col3[j] = array[i++];

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World! ' + col1[j]
        });
        j++;
    }
}

initialize();
```

**EDIT:**

To comment on the `var s2 = data.replace(/^.*$/, "").replace(/\r\n/g, " ");` line.. with the first replace I am removing the header row and the second one removes the new lines.

Comment: sorry couldnt work for me. There is no marker displayed. Just map displayed

Comment: Are you sure that your LatLong.txt file is being read in correctly?

Comment: Can you please drop your new merged code into a paste-bin for me?

Comment: @harold, I dint have account in that. But i have copied and pasted full code (see the updated one) and also the txt file texts. Let me make account to do that.

Comment: ok, so all you have done is move the map outside of the for loop. Please fix the other errors.

Comment: here si my code. It do not work but :  http://jsfiddle.net/shekharsinghshekhawat/0ohm6Lc8/2/

Comment: there is 1 more problem . It should be col1[j] = array[i];
        col2[j] = array[i+1];
        col3[j] = array[i+2];  But it still dont show marker on map when i read from file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q6k0xr1c/2/ check the edits I have made. Compare them with your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Marker array

```
var markers[];
```

Then in the loop you have to create to iterate over lat/longs, after marker is created put it into the array:

```
markers.push(marker);
```

In this way you can keep markers active...

Comment: This is not important as it will still work, but nevertheless a really, really good idea

Comment: if you don't create the array you will see only one marker in the map

Comment: Check out the fiddle I made for my answer http://jsfiddle.net/b4fz30vc/ you definately do not need the array.

Comment: true, what you can't is to control the tooltips!! great catch! +1

Comment: The title/tooltip works, but I think you are right in that it might be a pain to do infowindows and advanced stuff unless you did them in the for loop too, which would be a dog's breakfast ;)

Answer (score 0):

You create new map for every marker, so your output contains only the last map with the last marker. Try to move this code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

before the for loop

btw in your `for` loop you should increment your iterator by 3